# UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not work on MapKit (adapter)

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a view controller which gets an **adapter object** to be able to use MapKit.

On that adapter I implement 2 gesture (long press + tap) as always but **only long press does not work**.

How I prepare gestures:

```
private func prepareGestures(on pinView: PinViewProtocol) {
    let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(sender:)))
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = Constants.longPressDuration
    
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
    tapGesture.delegate = self
    
    pinView.addGestureRecognizers([tapGesture, longPressGesture])
}
```

How I add:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard let annotation = annotation as? MyPinAnnotation else {
        return nil
    }
    prepareGestures(on: pinView)
    return pinView
}
```

How I add that object in my view controller:

```
private func configureMapView() {
    mapViewAdapter = TestMapViewAdapter(mapView: mapView)
}
```

Comment: Add gesture recognizer `delegate` and implement `shouldBeRequiredToFailBy` to see what recogniser collides with it. Pretty sure mapkit installs bunch of recognisers which may have priority.

Comment: with implementation of this method, it recognizes long press. Thank you